# Как сделать корректное увеличение количества элементов при переходе на следующий уровень дерева

Tags: c++, дерево

Дерево, в котором в качестве указателей на потомков используется динамический массив. У корня N потомков, на каждом следующем уровне N удваивается. Никак не могу понять, как сделать корректное увеличение количества потомков(N) при переходе на следующий уровень.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
int lv=1;//уровень дерева
int maxl,N,N1,d,pp;
int dc = 0;
int s = 0;
using namespace std;
struct  tree
{        
    char *yk;            // указатель на строку
    tree* child;    //массив указателей на потомков
};

void viewTree(tree* begin, int sizeTree) {
    int power1 = 0, power2 = 1;
    int N = 1;
    tree* childTree = begin;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeTree; i++) {
        int u = 0;
        cout << "{";
        for (int j = 0; j < pow(2, power1); j++) {
            if (u == N) {
                u = 0;
                cout << "} {";
            }
            if (childTree->yk == NULL) {
                cout << "O";
            }
            else {
                cout << childTree->yk;
            }
            if (j != pow(2, power1) - 1 and u != N - 1) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            childTree++;
            u++;
        }
        cout << "}";
        childTree = childTree->child;
        cout << endl;
        power1 = power1 + power2;
        power2++;
        N = 2 * N;
    }
}
string rec(tree* ptr, int N) //функция построения дерева через рекурсию
{
    if (s != pp)
    {
        char c[15];
        tree* p = ptr;
        cout << "Enter the string: ";
        cin >> c;
        ptr->yk = new char[10];
        if (strcmp(c, "skip") == 0)
            memset(ptr->yk, '\0', 10);
        else
            strcpy_s(ptr->yk, 10, c);
        tree* temp = new tree;
        N *= 2;
        tree* child = new tree[N];
        ptr->child = child;
        if (lv == maxl)
        {
            dc++;
            if (dc == N1)
            {
                dc = 0;
                lv--;
                N = N / 2;
                return(ptr->yk);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (lv != maxl)lv++;
            rec(&ptr->child[i], N);
        }
        s++;
    }
    else { return(ptr->yk); }
}
string rec1(tree* ptr, int N) //функция обхода дерева
{
    tree* p = ptr;
    cout <<p->yk;
    if (lv >= maxl)
    {
        lv = 1;
        return(ptr->yk);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        lv++;
        if(lv=maxl)
        rec1(&p->child[i], N);
        rec1(&p->child[i], 2 * N);
    }
}
tree* Create(char val[],int N)
{
    tree* child = new tree[N];
    tree* tr;
    char *ch;
    tr = (struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    tr->yk =val;
    tr->child= new tree[N];
    rec(&tr->child[1],N);
    viewTree(tr,maxl);
    return(tr);
}
void add(tree* ptr, int a)
{
    struct tree* temp;
    temp = ptr;
    for (;;)
    {

    }
}//функция добавления элемента 
int main()
{
    pp = 0;
    d=1;
   // cout << "Enter the desired child number: ";
   // cin >> N;
    N = 2;
    N1 = N;
    tree* p;
    char value[10]; //массив для хранения содержимого ячейки
    //cout << "Enter the number of tree levels: ";
   // cin >> maxl;
    maxl = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxl-1; i++)
    {
        d *= N1;
        pp += d;
        if(i!=maxl-2)
        N1 *= 2;
    }
    pp--;
    cout << "Enter the value of the root: ";
    cin >> value;
    p = Create(value,N); //создание корня дерева
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.е. на втором уровне у каждого из N узлов 2N потомков, и всего получается

```
1 + N + 2*N^2
```

узлов, а при трёх и более уровнях

```
1 + N + 2*N^2 + 8*N^3
1 + N + 2*N^2 + 8*N^3 + 64*N^4
1 + N + 2*N^2 + 8*N^3 + 64*N^4 + 1024*N^5
```

В общем, на K-м уровне добавляется

```
2^(K*(K-1)/2) * N^K
```

узлов (степень двойки - "треугольные числа")